# Unable to Clone from Google Cloud Source Repository

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-source-repos

I have created a project (ID: imagetest1-259203) within an organization. I successfully created a repository using

```
gcloud source repos create repo1
```

but when I tried to clone this to my PC using

```
gcloud source repos clone repo1
```

I get the following issue. (**Note: I already have enabled "Cloud Source Repositories API"**)

```
Cloning into 'D:\AppEngineTests\repo1'...
remote: PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
remote: [type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo]
remote: request_id: "2e79f3c507f14b3190d7a5941bed3e5f"
fatal: unable to access 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/imagetest1-259203/r/repo1/': The requested URL returned error: 403
ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) Command '[u'git', u'clone', u'https://source.developers.google.com/p/imagetest1-259203/r/repo1', u'D:\\AppEngineTests\\repo1', u'--config', u'credential.helper=', u'--config', u'credential.helper=!gcloud.cmd auth git-helper --account=prabodar@xellmart.com --ignore-unknown $@']' returned non-zero exit status 128
```

But when I cloned to Cloud Shell using the same set of commands, it succeeded.

Comment: The issue was gone, when I used PowerShell (previously used command prompt) and then run 'git config --global http.cookiefile "%USERPROFILE%\.gitcookies" and run 'gcloud source repos clone repo1'. I wonder why it is gone by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to clone the contents of a Google Cloud Repository you need:

- authentication on your local system
- a repository in Cloud Source Repositories
- permissions to interact with the repository [link](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/cloning-repositories)

I suspect you have issues with permissions.

You have to install [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install).

Provide your authentication credentials:

```
gcloud init
```

and then clone the repository:

```
gcloud source repos clone [REPO_NAME] --project=[PROJECT_NAME]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for months, I was using two different accounts, personal & work.
It worked on one PC, but not another PC.

FIX: Rename or delete this file: %USERPROFILE%_netrc

I tried:

- gcloud auth revoke + then gcloud auth init
- Renamed .gitconfig
- Renamed .gitcookies
- Deleted %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\gcloud
- Deleted creds from Windows Credential Manager with 'git'
  Eventually ran procmon to trace which files it was reading.
- Renamed _netrc to _netrc.backup
  Command then worked.
  Undid rename and tested again, returned error message once again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the same issue was occurring because old login information was still stored in git. The problem was solved by deleting the ~/.gitcookies file.

- rm Rf ~/.gitcookies