# Permission denied with Google source repo

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-source-repositories

I've been using Google source repos for many years, and now I'm getting permission denied when I try to push or pull.

I've checked everything I can think of:

- Updated gcloud: `gcloud components update`
- Reinitialized: `gcloud init`
- Reinstalled gcloud tools
- Updated git
- Cloned repo to new directory (no permission)
- I still have access on the console: https://source.cloud.google.com/project/default
- Closed and reopened terminal
- I'm the owner of the organization and the project but I also added all source repository permissions

The above process sets my account and project so those are all set.

I just tried on a different computer (Windows 10), and I don't get permission denied.  The issue has something to do with my Mac setup...

Below are some examples:

```
$ git pull
remote: PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
remote: [type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo]
remote: request_id: "xxx"
fatal: unable to access 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/project/r/default/': The requested URL returned error: 403

$ gcloud source repos clone default --project=project
Cloning into '/Users/user/TMP/default'...
remote: PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
remote: [type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo]
remote: request_id: "xxx"
fatal: unable to access 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/project/r/default/': The requested URL returned error: 403
ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) Command '['git', 'clone', 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/project/r/default', '/Users/user/TMP/default', '--config', 'credential.https://source.developers.google.com/.helper=', '--config', 'credential.https://source.developers.google.com/.helper=!gcloud auth git-helper --account=me@example.com --ignore-unknown $@']' returned non-zero exit status 128.

$ git clone ssh://me@example.com@source.developers.google.com:2022/p/project/r/default
Cloning into 'default'...
me@example.com@source.developers.google.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Messages prefixed with `remote:` are coming not from Git itself, but from something the "remote Git" (the software running on your hosting provider, in this case Google) is running. That something, whatever it is, *should* tell you what is wrong and how to fix it. Git can't because as far as Git knows, everything is just fine. Git is just relaying a message.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are using a standard RSA key, which is not supported. You need to use another algorithm. Try creating a new one using the following command:

```
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -C "[USER_EMAIL]"
```

source: https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/authentication#ssh

Answer (score 0):

The first you can do is check the repository details and check the `access level` and the acces need to be set to `write`

Then go to tools -> Options and Authentication and delete all the passwords under `git saved password` or you could use the following commands:

`git config --system -l`

You will get,`credential.helper=!github --credentials`

And then use `git config --system --unset credential.helper` to remove the saved credentials (make sure you run this as an admin)

More on the subject on removing the credentials refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)

If removing the credentials doesn't work, here is another link to help you with the [403 error](https://www.a2hosting.in/kb/developer-corner/version-control-systems1/403-forbidden-error-message-when-you-try-to-push-to-a-github-repository) using the SSH or modifying the HTTPS URL

Comment: What does `tools -> Options and Authentication ` refer to?

Comment: I use the applicaion Sourcetree to delete the credentials, you can use any app that its convenient.  Sorry, I didnt mention it

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66522745/136598) to another to another similar question.

I didn't have the same file mentioned there, but I deleted `~/.netrc` and now git is working.

The `.netrc` file has been there since 2017.  No idea why that made a difference now...

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same. The repo existed and I had the correct permissions, but I still got the same error.

You have to add your ssh key to ssh agent

```
ssh-agent -s
ssh-add <pathtokey>
```

eg.

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This worked for me